# Numbers of different sub-arrays

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, sub-array

I have 2D binary array. Size: `M` x `N` For example `13` x `2` array can look like this:

`1010101010110
1010011111000`

Is it possible to say how many different 2d sub-arrays we can make? `M` x `N` array is sub-array too.

Without word `different` i think that number of sub-arrays is: `(n * (n + 1) * m * (m + 1)) / 4` is that true?

Comment: define the type of operation to select sub-array and the meaning of "different"

Comment: Different sizes. Values aren't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

**In Test**

Of course for the number of different sizes of sub-matrices it's just `m x n` because for each length of row, there is a length of column you could slice.

But for the more interesting question, how many permutations of a 2d array can you generate, the code below shows this:

```
permutations = []
for i in 1...m {
    for j in 1...n {
        // now we make all possible i x j matrices
        for k in 0..<floor(m / i) + 1 {
            for l in 0..<floor(n / j) + 1 {
                permutations.append(input[k:k+i,l:l+j])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so it's something like:

`m * n * (2m+1 + floor(m/2) + floor(m/3) + ... + floor(m / (m-1))) * (2n+1 + floor(n/2) + floor(n/3) + ... + floor(n / (n-1)))`